# contar ocurrencias de determinado valor en diccionario con claves int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un diccionario tramos_horas que calcula los tramos de luz, dependiendo de la hora es un tramo u otro.
En este caso, me gustaria sacar la frecuencia con la que el tramo "punta" ocurre en el diccionario.
El resultado tiene que ser 8 pues hay 8 horas en el dia en los que estamos en ese tramo.

```
tramos_horas = {}
for hora in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "valle"
for hora in 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "llana"
for hora in 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "punta"
```

El problema es que en internet hacen siempre uso de una clave o valor numerico para fijar el conteo pero en este caso entiendo que el elemento a buscar es "punta"

He probado varias funciones como len y count pero no encuentro la manera de filtrar el .values por "punta".
Tampoco tengo tanto conocimiento como para resolver este codigo.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Alternativa 1

La forma más trabajosa es recorrer el diccionario con un `for`, contando los elementos que cumplen la condición.

Cuando iteras sobre un diccionario, el iterador te devuelve las llaves, y teniendo la llave, puedo preguntar por el valor asociado:

```
contador = 0
for hora in tramos_horas:
    if tramos_horas[hora] == "punta":
        contador += 1
print(contador) => 8
```

#### Alternativa 2

Existen los métodos `keys` y `values` que retornan una lista de llaves y valores respectivamente. Puedo entonces recorrer la de valores contando las ocurrencias:

```
contador = 0
for tramo in tramos_horas.values():
    if tramo == "punta":
        contador += 1
print(contador) => 8
```

#### Alternativa 3

Usar una expresión generadora. Una expresión es como una comprensión de lista; se escribe igual, pero sin los `[]`.

La diferencia es la siguiente: la comprensión de lista retorna una lista con todos sus elementos, mientras que la expresión retorna elemento por elemento. La comprensión puede consume tanta memoria como elementos tenga la lista, mientras que la expresión sólo consume espacio para un elemento.

Esta expresión generadora recorre los valores del diccionario. Si el valor es "punta", genera un "1". La función `sum()` va sumando cada valor generado y su resultado es el número de veces que aparece "punta" en el diccionario.

```
contador = sum(1 for x in tramos_horas.values() if x == "punta")
print(contador) => 8
```

#### Alternativa 4

Usar la función `count(elemento)`, que dice cuantas veces ocurre el elemento en la lista:

```
contador = list(tramos_horas.values()).count("punta")
print(contador) => 8
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @CandidMoe! Osea al final la idea es transformar "punta" en un numero para poder hacer el conteo por lo que veo..

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias. Es una alternativa. En este caso ejemplifica las ventajas de aplicar transformaciones isomorficas.